# Which Regression to use including Code in R

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I am trying to predict a proportion take up rate. My dependant variable is between 0 and 10, meaning 0 and 10% have taken it up.

So it is not entirely continuous because it stops at 10 it doesn't go on forever.

It is a proportion as it is a % of the population grouped by postcode district so has about 2000 data points.
I am using demographic data so have about 10 different variables each with about 10 levels so that when I make dummy variables I have about 100 variables.
I am using R.
Question
I think from similar work that I can used model glm in R. and select family =  poisson() function.

I would like to check with the community that this is a good approach.

Comment: Can you clarify a few things for me... 1) Can your Y be > 0.1? (I know it isn't but could it be?)
2) Can your Y take any value between 0 and 0.1, or just ordinal steps (ie. 0, 0.01. 0.02, 0.03, etc...)?
3) Describe the shape of the histogram (or kernel density) of the measured Y values. Are they normally distributed, skewed one way or another?

Comment: Can you please clairfy how you obtained the underrlying data values for the "take-up rate".  Specifically, do you have access to the underlying population counts and take-up counts?  Why is it capped at 10%?  Was this just the highest observed value in the data, or is there some other reason for this cap (e.g., censoring)?

Comment: Answers: It could be higher than 10% but it is shopping in a postcode, it won't be 100% in real life.

Comment: The take up rate could be any number not just ordinal steps. If I round the numbers the distribution is                                                                                                             0    1      2      3     4     5     6     7    8   9  10 
300 826 589 410 286 138  68  19   7   6   9                                                                                                             
so skewed to low numbers, The 0 aren't really zero they are rounded to zero. I was thinking of cutting off at 6 unless you think I would lose information.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting I can't get it to paste a picture.

Comment: yes I have access to the counts, number or people and the total population to make the % take up